# (Beginner C++) Code not working

Tags: c++

So I have this code : http://pastebin.com/CSj5L1sM
what i want it to do is: every time i click W, A, S or D the hero("O") to move correspondingly in the multidimensional array. I dont want to dynamically modify it. Just to print a new one with the updated position of the hero string. The problem is nothing happens with i click the keys(WASD)! It only prints out the 2d array with "O" in the same place. Please help me i am still a beginner and i dont understand anything very good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is confused, you're trying to do too much at once. Separate out the different things you are trying to do. Like this

```
void generator(){
    // set the whole area to "+"
    for(int rows=0; rows<10; rows++)
        for(int cols=0; cols<10;cols++)
            gameArea[rows][cols] = "+";
    // set the position of the hero
    gameArea[x][y] = hero;
    // print the area
    for(int rows=0; rows<10; rows++)
    {
        for(int cols=0; cols<10;cols++)
            cout << gameArea[rows][cols];
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```